# How to Debug a Inconsistent Input Variables while Fitting a Linear Regression Model

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I am fitting my training dataset into a Linear Regression model, but it is showing value error as input variables are inconsistent with number of samples

The size of X is (16, 14)
The size of Y is (16,)

`regressor.fit(X_train,Y_train)`

> Error:Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [12, 4]